# Emulator process getting killed with Android Studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to start the emulator from Android Studio. It opens for seconds and then shut off and appears this error:

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3 was killed.
>   [image]

I think I've installed Pixel 3 emulator correctly and I have these SDK tools installed:

- Android SDK Build-Tools 30
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform-Tools
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

SDK Platform: Android 10.0+ (R)

I also already tried doing these steps but didn't work for me:
Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager
Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD
Change "Graphics" to "Software".

Any hints or ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this exact error.

For Android Studio v4.0 or above:

Menu -> Android Studio -> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator

Checked the Launch in a tool window option.

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYCLz.png)